# Handling Errors in ExecuteResult ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I have a file **DownloadResult.cs** extended from **ActionResult**(actually cloned from Phil Haack's one, which u can find at the following location [Phil's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/10/writing-a-custom-file-download-action-result-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx) )

Here how do i handle an exception(file not found ) thrown from the method **ExecuteResult()** in the controller level .

for the source code you might want to look at Phil's code , which is available at the link provided above.

looking forward for ur thoughts .

thanks,
vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a global error catching mechanism.

I recommend the approach explained in this question [How can I properly handle 404s in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc)

If you want a nicer message in your action result, you simply can add a `try catch` block and if the file does not exists:

```
 Throw New HttpException(404, "The file you want to download does not exists.")
```